# Display all the data/views in an Single activity in android emulator

Tags: android

I have edittext, checkbox, radiobutton, spinner etc in an activity, Due to which the spinner and radiobutton at the bottom are hidden in the emulator screen.

What can be the best solution for this?
Should I use scroll view?

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Can you please show us your view in picture that basically what is your need so that we can help you better.

Comment: Please share your layout xml

Comment: Yes , please use the scroll view. See you can screen can display a limited number of view to user, but if screen contains more components then its wise to user scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ScrollView so that the View that has no space to get into that...

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        //Your view here..like spinner ,button etc
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this could so